weird cosine approximation comprising some weird sums and the theta function. why and how?
I randomly got recommended a video of some guy approximating the cosine function, and they eventually arrive at
$$\cos{\pi x}\approx\lim_{R\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{R}\left(\frac{-D^{-\left(x+1-2n\right)^{2}}-D^{-\left(-x+1-2n\right)^{2}}+2D^{-\left(2n-1\right)^{2}}}{\sum_{i=1}^{R}\left(\frac{D^{8i-4}+1-2D^{4i-1}}{2D^{4i^{2}}}\right)}+\frac{1}{\sum_{I=1}^{R}1}\right)$$ where $D=\frac e2$. I think this is only approximately equal even with the limit.
I simplified this to
$$\frac{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(-D^{-\left(x+1-2n\right)^{2}}-D^{-\left(-x+1-2n\right)^{2}}+2D^{-\left(2n-1\right)^{2}}\right)}{\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{D^{8i-4}+1-2D^{4i-1}}{2D^{4i^{2}}}\right)}+1$$
and then to $$\cos{\pi x}=\frac{\frac12\left(\vartheta_2\left(0,\frac{16}{e^4}\right)+\vartheta_3\left(0,\frac{16}{e^4}\right)\right)-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(D^{-(x-(2n+1))^2}+D^{-(x+(2n+1))^2}\right)}{\frac12\left(\vartheta_2\left(0,\frac{16}{e^4}\right)-\vartheta_3\left(0,\frac{16}{e^4}\right)\right)}$$ where $\vartheta_a(x,q)$ is the theta function (jacobi's).
What in the hell? Forgive me for uneducatedly messing around. Wolfram Alpha refuses to compute that sum in the last equation and probably for good reason.
Is there some way to get this to actually equal cosine if it does not already? And if it does already, how?

Your last formula seems to evaluate very close to $-\cos(\pi x)$ so it appears you have a sign error.

These formulas don't seem that practical. You can look up efficient numerical approximations of sine/cosine if you want that. Typically C++ is used for that kind of fast numerical calculation

This really looks like an inverse Fourier transform of two shifted Dirac deltas, where the Dirac delta is represented by an infinite sum.   I doubt there's some profound mystery here, but rather an interesting representation of a Dirac delta.
